# how to access payment gateways in iphone application

Tags: iphone

I need to access payment gateways (master or visa) in my iphone application. Any one can help me, how can i get it?

Comment: You should accept more answers (or write better questions that can actually be answered).

Comment: What research have you done on your own?

Comment: Your question is far too broad btw. Please read http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you will need to interact with your payment gateway using the exposed API. However, be aware that Apple will likely reject your application if you do so (they require using their in app store in most cases for payment processing). I recommend you read the guidelines.